# mongoose objects with synchronous utility methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, instance-methods

I have an Express.js node app that uses mongoose. I was wondering if it is possible to make synchronous utility method for my models.

For example, if my model has first- and lastname as two fields, it would be great to be able to make a method like

```
myModelSchema.fullname = function(){return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname}
```

Similarly, if I have a model that contains integer references to a list of choices, It would be great to have a method that return the choice instead of just the stored integer.

As far as I've seen in the docs, it is only possible to add methods like

```
myModelSchema.methods.myFunction = function(callback) {...}
```

Which makes it asynchronous. I'd like to not do that, but if that is the only way, could I just make a "prepare" function, and then when .finding() instances, do something like

```
MyModel.find({...})
.exec()
.prepare(function (err, models) {...})
```

Or something similar?

Please let me know what is possible, and what is the best approach :)

Comment: Why does `myModelSchema.methods.myFunction = function(callback) {...}` make it asynchronous? Have you tried virtuals? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html

Comment: I love how the example in the documentation matches my example exactly. Don't see how I missed it. Exactly what I needed. Thanks :)